# inserting a value into database depending on id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert my data into a table depending on the value I select from the drop down.
Actually I have two tables, `Categories` and `Products`. Both are interlinked with `CategoryID`.
Now I have a form through this I am trying to add a product. I have a dropdown for categories. I will select a category from the dropdown and then I will add related products to that category.

After getting the form data, I fetched my table for `CategoryID` like this:

```
 include('includes/conn.php');
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
     $CategoryName = $_POST['cat'];
     echo $CategoryName; 
     $ProductName = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['ProductName']));
     $ProductCode = $_POST['ProductCode'];
     $Specification = $_POST['Specification'];
     $Description = $_POST['Description'];
     $CostPrice = $_POST['CostPrice'];
     $DisplayPrice = $_POST['DisplayPrice'];
     $ProductID = $_POST['ProductID'];
     $Productimage = $_POST['ProductImage'];
     $sql = "select * Categories";
     $result = mysql_query ($sql);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     $Category_ID = $row['CategoryID'];
```

after this I am not getting how to do. Except that condition my code inserts the record successfully.
my complete code withouth selecting the categoryid like this

```
<?php 
}

include('includes/conn.php');
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    { 
        $ProductName = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['ProductName']));
        $ProductCode = $_POST['ProductCode'];
        $Specification = $_POST['Specification'];
        $Description = $_POST['Description'];
        $CostPrice = $_POST['CostPrice'];
        $DisplayPrice = $_POST['DisplayPrice'];
        $ProductID = $_POST['ProductID'];
        $Productimage = $_POST['ProductImage'];
        if ($ProductName == '' || $ProductCode == ''|| $Specification == '' || $Description == '' || $CostPrice == '' || $DisplayPrice =='')
        {
            echo  "Please fill in all required fields";
            renderForm($ProductID, $ProductName, $ProductCode, $Description, $Specification, $CostPrice, $DisplayPrice,  $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT into Products SET ProductName='$ProductName', ProductCode='$ProductCode', Specification ='$Specification', Description = '$Description', CostPrice = $CostPrice, DisplayPrice = $DisplayPrice, ProductImage = '$ProductImage'";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            echo " Successfully Added "; 
            //header("Location: view.php"); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        renderForm('','','','','','','','','');
    }
   ?>
```

Please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, ProductCode, ...) VALUES ('".$ProductName."', '". $ProductCode ."', ...";
```

This is how you use an insert query.

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlinsert.php

Comment: Make sure to use a combination of sprintf and mysql_real_escape_string() to shield your database

Comment: Yes, i have corrected my insert query but thats not my problem. I want to insert the data where the cateoryid exists